# java customize a hashmap values

Tags: caching, collections, types, iterator, hashmap

I am working on using a real time application in java, I have a data structure that looks like this.

```
HashMap<Integer, Object> myMap;
```

now this works really well for storing the data that I need but it kills me on getting data out. The underlying problems that I run into is that if i call

```
Collection<Object> myObjects = myMap.values();
Iterator<object> it = myObjects.iterator();
while(it.hasNext(){ object o = it.next(); }
```

I declare the iterator and collection as variable in my class, and assign them each iteration, but iterating over the collection is very slow. This is a real time application so need to iterate at least 25x per second.

Looking at the profiler I see that there is a new instance of the iterator being created every update.

I was thinking of two ways of possibly changing the hashmap to possibly fix my problems.
1. cache the iterator somehow although i'm not sure if that's possible.
2. possibly changing the return type of hashmap.values() to return a list instead of a collection
3. use a different data structure but I don't know what I could use.

Comment: If you're accessing the full map entry you'd be better off using the `entrySet` rather than `values`.  Have you tried using one of the `FastMap` implementations?  Overall needing to iterate that much seems like an issue itself.

Comment: hi Matt, I did try to use fast map but performance is about the same, its iterating over the collections<V> that's the problem. I wish there was some way to return the underlying array<V> that way seems like it would be a good option *if it can be implemented* but so far I haven't really been able to.

Comment: Why are you using a map?  If you're iterating that often it sounds like a list would be a better idea anyway.

Comment: My data structure is setup like this `HashMap<Class<?>, HashMap<Integer, Object>> myMap;` I am not sure how to model that relationship with lists, i've tried tuples and a whole range of other data structures but maybe I am over engineering it because I've yet to come up with a reasonable solution.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still open use Google Guava collections.  They have things like multiMap for the structures you are defining.   Ok, these might not be an exact replacement, but close:
From the website here:  https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

Every experienced Java programmer has, at one point or another, implemented a Map> or Map>, and dealt with the awkwardness of that structure. For example, Map> is a typical way to represent an unlabeled directed graph. Guava's Multimap framework makes it easy to handle a mapping from keys to multiple values. A Multimap is a general way to associate keys with arbitrarily many values.